# Deleting highlighted text in UITextDocumentProxy

Tags: swift

So I'm making a [custom keyboard extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1) and one issue I'm coming across is deleting text that is highlighted.

currently there's a delete button that is supposed to delete whatever is in the text box, but when there is text highlighted that text isn't deleted.

Possible solutions I've come with so far

**1: Make it so the text is unhighlighted and erase from there**

**2 Add the highlighted text to the unhighlighted text (not gonna work probably)**

**3. Automatically cut all text that is highlighted**

**4. Use `func setMarkedText(String, selectedRange: NSRange)`**

I wanna say 4 would be the best way to do it, not sure how I would implement it though

*Docs to UITextDocumentProxy: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextdocumentproxy)*

Here is the code I currently have that works on non highlighted text

```swift
    if let after: String = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput {
      self.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: after.count)
    }
    if let word: String = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput {
      for _: Int in 0 ..< word.count {
        self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
      }
```

Really lost at where to start, since I can grab highlighted text, but can't change it according to the docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Here is what I did in case anyone has a similar issue.

```
  if(self.textDocumentProxy.selectedText != nil) {
print(self.textDocumentProxy.selectedText!)
  var selectedText = self.textDocumentProxy.selectedText?.count
  self.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: selectedText!)
}
if let after: String = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput {

  self.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: after.count)
}

if let word: String = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput {
  for _: Int in 0 ..< word.count {
    self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
  }
```

Comment: This is a good start, but will unfortunately not work as expected, since `textDocumentProxy.documentContextBefore/AfterInput` doesn't return *all* the text. Any paragraph or new line can make it abort fetching text and leave you with a partial result.